# How to convert a GIF image browsed from storage to InputStream in Android?

Tags: android, inputstream, gif

I'm able to convert a gif image from assets folder to InputStream like shown below

```
        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = getAssets().open("my_gif.gif");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How to convert the gif data obtained by ACTION_PICK intent

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == SELECT_GALLERY_IMAGE) {
// here gif is present in data.getData()
}
```

how to convert data.getData() to InputStream

Comment: see `ContentResolver` documentation on how to open any `Uri`

Comment: sure, your welcome...